# Spring Integration with Struts .. Why?

Tags: struts2

Can Anyone please tell why we need to integrate springs with struts.. Wat is the use of doing so?
some are mentioned "dependency injection that can be useful to any framework" what does it really mean?

Comment: you can work independently with struts that's for spring Ioc lovers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) allows easy substitution of implementations. One of the greatest benefits comes during testing: I can inject implementations with known behavior and bypass other system components.

DI is available inside S2 already, via XWork--but considering how much of Spring's functionality is generally useful anyway, I almost always use Spring for essentially all my DI/IoC as well.